# Why does my dog sniff plant's

Tags: dogs, plants

My dog keeps sniffing plants in the night when I watch movies or YouTube, since I don't want to watch YouTube or Movies in the morning. Everytime I watch in the night, he keeps coming to my plants and sniffing them. I tried to research this topic but I couldn't find anything relevant to my search. Can someone explain a good reason why my dog sniff plants.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Does the dog do this in the night only? Only at home? How old, which gender and is the dog neutered? Was it a stray? What exactly is the dog doing before and after the sniffing?

Comment: Additionally, what type of plants are they?

Comment: @Allerleirauh I don't remember his age, and he is male, he was born from a sick dog. Before sniffing he was doing normal doggy things, the dog only does this at night, he does it only at home.

Comment: @JacobB uhm I don't know, I think a flowering plant, I got it from the store.

Comment: Without more information we can not answer the question. Guessing is not welcome here. So you need to research further on your own.

Comment: Given the circumstances, it's entirely possible that your dog simply likes the smell of the plants. Dogs frequently sniff things that have new or interesting odors, and it may just be that you only notice the dog sniffing it when you're around watching movies.